# Google Search Individual pages show up in search

Tags: search

Quick question...  when i search for my sites in google, the individual pages on my site show up for example. When I search my website, it shows the pages for gallery and contact when I just want it to show the main index/homepage for the site.. and not show the individual page sections (gallery and contact)..

thanks

Comment: i am not sure if this belongs to SO, as this is more about google than about programming..

Answer (score 0):

it is because in google's eye, your subpage (contact, gallery, ..) is optimized for that keyword instead of the homepage. You will need to optimize the homepage for that keyword if you want to show homepage for the keyword.

Comment: no. that's not what I said. you need to optimize your homepage for the keyword you want. if you do not understand what I mean, maybe ask a seo guy is a better choice.